# Why won't excluding a specific folder work while I'm making a .zip file?

Tags: command-line, zip

I want to make a zip file of a directory except a specific folder which is into it. Here is my command:

```
zip -r -x 'public/images/' tw.zip /var/www/html/m4/
```

I want to make a zip of this `/var/www/html/m4/` except `public/images/` folder which exists into it. But my command throws this error message:

```
zip error: Invalid command arguments (nothing to select from)
```

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The zip man page says:

```
zip ... [zipfile [file ...]] [-xi list]
```

so, the zip file name and the path to the structure you want to compress should come before your exclude list.

This part of your command will not be applied correctly:

```
-x 'public/images/'
```

Because it does not specify files in the way zip recognises.

This will work:

```
zip -r my.zip /var/www/html/m4/ -x /var/www/html/m4/public/images/\*
```

- As you know, `-r` is recursive.
- `-x`is used to exclude (files),
- `\` before `*` is used to avoid filename expansion by the shell; we leave that to `zip`.